# Accessing 1st party cookies in Firefox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, firefox, cookies

I'm having a problem with my if statement in firefox. As you can see in the code below, I'm checking if a cookie exists and if it does exist, it writes out some JS for google analytics, and if it doesn't exist it writes a div box with a cookiewarning.

It's working in all browsers except firefox. Anybody know why it isn't working in Firefox?

```
if (Request.Cookies["CookieConfirm"] != null)
   {
         litHead.Text = puts out my js for google analytics
   }

else
   {
         litCookieAlert.Text += puts out the divbox and some links
   }
```

Comment: Does Firefox actually have the cookie on the page when you check for this?

Comment: Yes, when i click the accept button in the div box, it makes the cookie, and the div box doesnt show again, so some of the if statement must be working in firefox, but it doesnt wrtie the JS, after i clicked yes to the cookie and i check the sourcecode in the browser, the JS isn't written